# Phrase corpus for sentimental analysis

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Good day,
I'm attempting to write a sentimental analysis application in python (Using naive-bayes classifier) with the aim to categorize phrases from news as being positive or negative.
And I'm having a bit of trouble finding an appropriate corpus for that.
I tried using "General Inquirer" (http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/homecat.htm) which works OK but I have one big problem there.
Since it is a word list, not a phrase list I observe the following problem when trying to label the following sentence:

> He is not expected to win.

This sentence is categorized as being positive, which is wrong. The reason for that is that "win" is positive, but "not" does not carry any meaning since "not win" is a phrase.
Can anyone suggest either a corpus or a work around for that issue?
Your help and insight is greatly appriciated.

Comment: As a side note: Do you expect naive Bayes to work here? Let's say that all of our features are "win", "lose", and "not", and "win" and "lose" appear in equal proportions. Then either "win" or "not win" will be misclassified.

Comment: I believe that's why he's asking about using phrases as features.

Comment: I think he's using words as features to classify phrases...

Comment: Currently I'm using words, yes. This is why I'm asking if there is a way to still use words and in some way account for the negative words like "not" etc while using the word corpus or if anyone can direct me to a phrase corpus for sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for example: "What's great and what's not: learning to classify the scope of negation for improved sentiment analysis" by Councill, McDonald, and Velikovich

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1858959.1858969

and followups,

http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=3029019835762139237&as_sdt=5,33&sciodt=0,33&hl=en

e.g. by Morante et al 2011

http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00007634/

Comment: Thank you Georgy. I'll definitely have a look.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the work *not* modifies the meaning of the phrase *expecteed to win*, reversing it. To identify this, you would need to POS tag the sentence and apply the negative adverb *not* to the (I think) verb phrase as a negation. I don't know if there is a corpus that would tell you that not would be this type of modifier or not, however.

Comment: I love your very differently scoped use of the word "not" near the end of that.  Good luck to all our algorithms figuring out what that's negating!  :-)